# Nested GroupBy in c# Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, group-by, nested

I need to create a var for nested groupby items

Data Set : 
Item : grocery dop : 01/Jan/2019 Value : 2000 rs
Item : cell dop : 04/Mar/2019 Value : 10000 rs
Item : clothes dop : 05/Jan/2019 Value : 15000 rs
Item : Veggies dop : 06/Jan/2019 Value : 1500 rs
Item : grocery dop : 04/Jan/2019 Value : 1000 rs
Item : Veggies dop : 06/Jan/2019 Value : 200 rs
Item : tea dop : 04/Feb/2019 Value : 10 rs

I need the output like below

for loop (monthwise)
Jan Month in a grouped var based on Item Name
Item : clothes dop : 05/Jan/2019 Value : 15000 rs (Highest Value should come first)
Item : grocery dop : 01/Jan/2019 Value : 2000 rs  (Same Item name )
Item : grocery dop : 04/Jan/2019 Value : 1000 rs  (Same Item name )
Item : Veggies dop : 06/Jan/2019 Value : 1500 rs  (Same Item name )

Feb
Item : tea dop : 04/Feb/2019 Value : 10 rs

Mar
Item : cell dop : 04/Mar/2019 Value : 10000 rs

var groupListDop = expDetailsList.GroupBy(x => x.Dop.Month);
 foreach (var month in groupListDop)
 {
        foreach (var day in month)
        {
And I want to print the item occurance  also ie. grocery ( 3 times ) veggies (2 times ) clothes (1 times ) 
        }
}

Comment: Add some code with what your data structures look like, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: var groupListDop = expDetailsList.GroupBy(x => x.Dop.Month).OrderBy(x=> x.Key).Select(x=>new { Key = x.Key,
                SingleGroup = x.OrderBy(y=>y.Item) , Total = x.Sum(y => y.Value), Num = x.Distinct().Count() }).Distinct().ToList(); </br> foreach (var month in groupListDop) </br>
            { </br> Console.WriteLine("Month " + month.Key + " month Number " + month.Num + " Total " + month.Total) ; </br> foreach (var day in month.SingleGroup)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("day " + day.Item + day.Dop + day.Value);</br>
                    
                }

Comment: What's the data structures of dop? Is it a model?